# Sharepoint subsite's home page is empty

Tags: sharepoint-server

I am using the trial version of the Sharepoint 2013 and I realized that everytime when I create a new subsite, it is always empty:

[image]

But a lot of tutorials, they will show something like

[image]

Am I missing anything (i.e. do I need to do any configuration anywhere)?

Thanks

Comment: Does it only happen for subsites ?  Your site collection renders correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reconfigure SharePoint 2013, there might be some configuration issues. Just re-run the configuration wizard and try again

Answer (score 0):

This could also be due to browser issues inside server environment. Please check it in browsers outside your server.

Comment: Hi @Mp Arvind, care to elaborate? Cos don't really understand what you meant. :)

Comment: Can you try removing " _layouts/15/start.aspx# " From your url and tell if the site is loading properly ?

Comment: It redirects automatically to the URL you mention (with the  _layouts/15/start.aspx).